# Macro expansion in context of arithmetic expression?

Tags: c++, c

I saw this below code in an website.
I could not able to understsnd how the result is coming as `11`, instead of `25` or `13`.

Why I am thinking `25` because `SQ(5) 5*5`

or `13` because

`SQ(2) = 4;`

`SQ(3) = 9;`

may be final result will be `13 (9 + 4)`
But surprised to see result as `11`.
How the result is coming as `11`?

```
using namespace std;
#define SQ(a) (a*a)
int main()
{
    int ans = SQ(2 + 3);
    cout << ans << endl;
system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`#define` expansions kick in before the compiler sees the source code. That is why they are called *pre-processor directives*, the processor here is the compiler that translates C to machine readable code.

So, this is what the macro pre-processor is passing on to the compiler:

`SQ(2 + 3)` is expanded as `(2 + 3*2 + 3)`

So, this is really `2 + 6 + 3` = `11`.

How can you make it do what you expect?

1. Enforce the order of evaluation. Use (), either in the macro definition or in the macro call.
   OR
2. Write a simple function that does the job

Answer (score 19):

The preprocessor does a simple text substitution on the source code. It knows nothing about the underlying language or its rules.

**In your example, `SQ(2 + 3)` expands to `(2 + 3*2 + 3)`, which evaluates to `11`.**

A more robust way to define `SQ` is:

```
#define SQ(a) ((a)*(a))
```

Now, `SQ(2 + 3)` would expand to `((2 + 3)*(2 + 3))`, giving `25`.

Even though this definition is an improvement, it is still not bullet-proof. If `SQ()` were applied to an expression with [side effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29), this could have undesired consequences. For example:

- If `f()` is a function that prints something to the console and returns an `int`, `SQ(f())` would result in the output being printed twice.
- If `i` is an `int` variable, `SQ(i++)` results in [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

For further examples of difficulties with macros, see [Macro Pitfalls](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macro-Pitfalls.html).

For these reasons it is generally preferable to use functions rather than macros.

Comment: A more robust way is to use a function for this.

Comment: @JanDvorak: They are, until one accidentally applies `SQ()` to an expression with side effects.

Comment: @NPE what do you mean side effects? sorry,i know it sounds like I should know

Comment: @fersarr: Consider `SQ(f())`. If `f()` prints something to the console, you'd unexpectedly see the output twice.

Comment: @fersarr Statements like SQ(func()) or SQ(a++) will give unexpected results even with a ().

Comment: Macros are never safe, and besides, they are a pain to debug.

Comment: @NPE: From where this `3*2` came from?

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak: When you replace `a` with `2 + 3` in `a*a`, you get `2 + 3*2 + 3`. Think textual substitution.

Answer (score 3):

The C preprocessor does textual substitution before the compiler interprets expressions and C syntax in general. Consequently, running the C preprocessor on this code converts:

```
SQ(2 + 3)
```

into:

```
2 + 3*2 + 3
```

which simplifies to:

```
2 + 6 + 3
```

which is 11.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a replacement before compilation

so you should try this out :

```
#define SQ(a) ((a)*(a))
```

In your case , `SQ(2 + 3)` is equivalent to `(2+3*2+3)` which is `11`.

But correcting it to as I wrote above, it will be like, `((2+3)*(2+3))` which is `5*5 = 25` that's the answer you want.

Comment: Because everything is *not* fine... What happens when I call this macro as `SQ(a++)`? The result is `((a++)*(a++))`. Is that what I intended? Chances are that no, it's not. You cannot *reliably* reference a macro argument more than once inside the macro. It's a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 1):

**#define** preprocesor

Syntax : 
 **# define identifier replacement**

1. When the preprocessor encounters this directive, it replaces any occurrence of identifier in the rest of the code by replacement.
2. This replacement can be an expression, a statement, a block or simply anything.
3. The preprocessor does not understand C, it simply replaces any occurrence of identifier by replacement.

**# define can work also with parameters to define function macros:**

**`# define SQ(a) (a*a)`**

will replace any occurance of SQ(a) with a*a at compile time.
Hence,

SQ(2+3) will be replaces by 2+3*2+3
The computation is performed after the replacement is done.
hence answer 2+3*2+3=11

Answer (score 1):

For your implementation, the value will expand to `2+3 * 2+3` which will result into 2+6+3=11.

You should define it as:

```
#define SQ(x) ({typeof(x) y=x; y*y;})
```

Tested on `gcc`, for inputs like

1. constants,
2. variable,
3. constant+const
4. const+variable
5. variable++ / ++variable
6. function call, containing printf.

Note: `typeof` is GNU addition to standard C. May not be available in some compilers.

Comment: I guess you mean 2+6+ **3** =11. ;)